# Identical equation $\sin(\frac{nx}{2^{n-1}})=\sin x\times \sin(x+\pi/n)\times \cdot\cdot\cdot \times \sin(x+\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}) $

Tags: trigonometric-series

> Using $\;\;\sin(\frac{nx}{2^{n-1}})=\sin x\times \sin(x+\pi/n)\times \cdots \times \sin(x+\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}) $
>   Simplify the following expression. $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\cot(x+\frac{(k-1)\pi}{n})}$$

Choices are { $n\cot(nx)$ }, { $\cot(nx)/n$ }, { $\frac{n\cot(nx)}{2^{n-1}}$ }, and { $\frac{\cot(nx)}{2^{n-1}}$ }.

---

What I've tried so far are,

Let $a_n=\sin(\frac{nx}{2^{n-1}})$
$n=1,\; \sin(x)=\sin(x) \\
n=2, \;\sin(x)=\sin(x)\cdot \sin(x+1/2\pi) \quad \therefore \sin(x+1/2\pi)=1\\
n=3, \;\sin(3x/4)=\sin(x)\cdot \sin(x+1/2\pi)\cdot \sin(x+2/3\pi) =\sin(x)\cdot \sin(x+2/3\pi) \\
\cdots \\
\;\text{ then,} \quad \sin(x+\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n})=a_n/a_{n-1} $

$\cos(x+\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n})=\sin(x+\pi/2+\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n})$

How should I solve it?

Comment: Take logarithm & differentiate

Comment: Thanks. I got to $\frac{2^{n-1} \cdot \sin(\frac{nx}{2^{n-1}})}{n}=\frac{1}{sinx}+\frac{1}{sin(x+\pi/n)} \cdot\cdot\cdot \frac{1}{sin(x+\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n})}$. How can I put $cos$ terms in the numerator?

Comment: Your first formula is not right: I think it should be $$\frac{\sin nx}{2^{n-1}}=\cdots$$